# "ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full" , however, disk space is fine, innodb_data_file_path autoextend

Tags: mysql

This error happens when I try to create a new table like this:

[image]

Then when I tried to reinstall MySQL, same error popped out when initiation.

[image]

According to the 'df -h', I have plenty of space.
innodb_data_file_path is set to ibdata1:12M:autoextend

I have run out of ideas, really hope I can have some suggestion here. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a new install, correct? I would recommend you start with a minimum configuration file first and try to reinitialize. With a my.cnf configuration you can leave off the `basedir` and `datadir` options. These should be in your my.cnf file.

Comment: What is `--user=k_d239`??, I think it wants to have --user=mysql because that's who owns the tables and can add or delete

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was oviously the 32-Bit-Mysql (5.7), which gave that error in InnoDB-Tables reaching 4GB.

System: MS-Server 2008R2, 64-Bit / MySql 5.7 32-Bit / InnoDB-Tables.

Switching to 64-Bit-Mysql solved it.

MyIsam-Files >4GB worked fine with 32-Bit-MySql.

(I intended to install 32-Bit because of our 32-Bit-Software to work with - but in 64-Bit it works well - just didn't know )

Answer (score 0):

What is `--user=k_d239`??, I think it wants to have `--user=mysql` because that's who owns the tables and can add or delete. In fact , you should probably skip that completely, as it's reserved to be run as `root`

Comment: Dear Jacques Amar,Thank you so much for your reply. I'm reinstalling it as a non-root user: k_d239. I've used parameter '-DMYSQL_USER=k_d239 \' when cmake.
I did the whole thing one time before and it was working, it failed this time with the error message "the table is full", same as that when I create a talbe before the MySQL is uninstalled. Sincerely, Kang